# get contact number when contact is added / change / delete

Tags: android-contacts, contentobserver

I want contact number for my android application when **any new contact added or contact is edited / deleted from android in built app.**

I have tried below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
    }

    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            Log.e("contact ", "Changed or added");
            Log.e("URI",uri.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

I can see log when **contact is added / edited / deleted.** But i have got stuck to get a particular contact number **which is added / edited / deleted** from android inbuilt application.

what should i write in **onChange()** to get contact number?

**My main requirement is i do not want to read all contact from android phone. I just want a single contact number which is newly added / edited / deleted.**

Anyone know about this? please guide me.